# How to change the color of a td dynamically according to the value?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to show `<td>` value in red and green colour. If "DETECTED" red and if "NO DETECTION" green colour font should come. `@model.status` should change the colour of font dynamically

**view**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.UpdatedTime</td>
        <td>@Model.status</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**controller**

```
if (status == "UP") {
    ViewBag.data = "OPEN";
    ViewBag.StatusImg = "/images/intrusion.jpg";
    model.status = "DETECTED";
    model.ImageUrl = "/images/normal.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I think your code is not formatted properly. How you are getting </tbody> inside controller? Please post full code

Comment: modify td with: <td bgcolor="@(Model.Status=="DETECTED" ? "red" : "green")">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if-else block inside view in Razor

```
 <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.UpdatedTime</td>
            @if(Model.status == "DETECTED"){
                <td style="background-color:red">Model.status</td>
            } else{
                <td style="background-color:green">Model.status</td>
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```